# Function:Compute Price in Python- Price of Drawers

Tags: python, function

I need to do a program that has a function:

- that accepts the number of drawers in the desk as input from the keyboard. This function returns the number of drawers to the main() function.
- that accepts as input and return the type of wood--'m' for mahogany, 'o' for oak, or 'p' for pine.
- that take as parameters the number of drawers and the wood type, and calculates the cost of the desk
- that displays all the details and the final price.
- a main function

I already have the cost with only the main function. I just don't know how to split it up into four different functions.
Here is my code:

```
def main(): 

    r = int(input("Enter number of drawers >> ")) #prompting user for input
    extra = 30 * r
    drawers = input("Enter type of wood - m, o, or p >> ") 
    if drawers == 'm':
        ans = 180 + extra
        if r == 1: #if statement
            print("You have ordered a mahogany desk with 1 drawer")
        else:
            print("You have ordered a mahogany desk with",r,"drawers")


    if drawers == 'p':#if statement
        ans = 100 + extra
        if r == 1:#if statement
            print("You have ordered a pine desk with 1 drawer")
        else:
            print("You have ordered a pine desk with",r,"drawers")

    if drawers == 'o':#if statement
        ans = 140 + extra
        if r == 1:#if statement
            print("You have ordered a oak desk with 1 drawer")
        else:
            print("You have ordered a oak desk with",r,"drawers")

    elif drawers == 'o':
        ans = 140 + extra
    elif drawers == 'p':
        ans = 100 + extra
    print("Total price is $"+str(ans)) #printing total price

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this simple sketch and fill in your existing logic:

```
def drawer_count():
    drawers = int(input("How many drawers?")
    return drawers

def wood_type():
    wood = input("Which type of wood")
    return wood

def calc_price(wood, drawers):
    ...
    return total

def checkout(wood, drawers, total):
    print(...)

def main():
    wood = wood_type()
    drawers = drawer_count()
    total = calc_price(wood, drawers)
    checkout(wood, drawers, total)
```